# boolean variable unavailable in getView()

Tags: android, baseadapter

I never understand the `getView()` method fully. Here is a case:

[image]

Here I have `isNoticeRead` which is false you can see. But the line gets executed! And when the line in the if statement is executing, `isNoticeRead` is not found anywhere! If I even place my cursor over it, nothing happens (no tooltip). And it happens for the first `item` of the `ListView`. Can you please tell me what am I missing?

My full `Adapter`

```
public class NoticesListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    Context context;
    ArrayList<NoticeModel> items;
    String[] readNotices;

    public NoticesListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NoticeModel> items) {
        this.context                                    = context;
        this.items                                      = items;
        readNotices                                     = SharedPrefUtils.getMarkedNotices(context).split(SharedPrefUtils.SEPARATOR_READ_NOTICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Holder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            convertView                                 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_notices, null);
            holder                                      = new Holder();
            holder.noticeID                             = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noticeID);
            holder.tvNotice                             = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNotice);
            holder.tvDateTime                           = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateTime);
            holder.tvNoticeRead                         = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNoticeRead);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder                                      = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            String str = items.get(position).getId() + "";
            holder.noticeID.setText(str);
            holder.tvNotice.setText(items.get(position).getText());
            holder.tvDateTime.setText(DateTimeUtils.changeDateTimeFormat(items.get(position).getDateTime(), DateTimeUtils.FORMAT8, DateTimeUtils.FORMAT3));

            final boolean isNoticeRead = items.get(position).isRead();
            if (isNoticeRead) {
                holder.tvNoticeRead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        //        for(String s : readNotices) {
        //            if (s.equals(str)) {
        //                holder.tvNoticeRead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ////                break;
        //            }
        //        }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        return convertView;
    }

    class Holder{
        TextView tvNotice, tvDateTime, noticeID, tvNoticeRead;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The views of your holder are being re-used by the List. Thus you may have an instance which is initialized with VISIBLE, but when the view is reused and filled, you don't reset its state - so it is still visible.

```
if (isNoticeRead) {
    holder.tvNoticeRead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    holder.tvNoticeRead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you make variable final then it's means unable to assigned value during execute because you make it final remove final or define isNoticeRead as field.
then it may be work fine for you..